# Reading Lines From Delimited File in C#

Tags: c#, delimiter, readfile

I have a program where I'm trying to have the ability to take information they entered into the program and store it into a template file of sorts, so it can be saved and reloaded easily. The template format looks like this

```
#START#1 -- Contact#END#
#START#1 -- Error
2 -- Error
3 -- Error#END#
#START#1 -- Actions
2 -- Actions
3 -- Actions
4 -- Actions#END#
#START#1 -- Res
2 -- Res
3 -- Res#END#
#START#WorkedWith#END#
#START#3011#END#
#START#1 -- Details
2 -- Details
3 -- Details#END#
```

Everything between the `#START#` and `#END#` tags is a value that needs to be stored in a different variable.

For instance the first variable would need to contain

```
1 -- Contact
```

The second variable would need to contain

```
1 -- Error
2 -- Error
3 -- Error
```

And so on until the 7th variable contains the Details second.

What is the easiest way to go about reading the file and storing the data between the delimiters into variables?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For Sakura

Code:

```
string sInput = "";
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sTemplateFilePath))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        sInput = sInput + line;

    }
    reader.Close();
}
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(sInput, "#START#(.*?)#END#", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled))
{
    foreach (var line in m.Groups[1].Value.Split('\n'))
    {
        switch (iLineCount)
        {
            case 0:
                sContactReason = line;
            break;

            case 1:
                sError = line;
            break;

            case 2:
                sActionsTaken = line;
            break;

            case 3:
                sResolution = line;
            break;

            case 4:
                sL3 = line;
            break;

            case 5:
                sKB = line;
            break;

            case 6:
                sDetails = line;
            break;
        }

        iLineCount++;

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 -- Contact

1 -- Error2 -- Error3 -- Error

1 -- Actions2 -- Actions3 -- Actions4 -- Actions

1 -- Res2 -- Res3 -- Res

WorkedWith

3011

1 -- Details2 -- Details3 -- Details
```

Comment: What should happen to any text that appears between a `#END#` and a `#START#`?  Should such text be ignored?

Comment: @KenClement There shouldn't ever be text between `#END#` and `#START#` realistically. (Except new lines) so I'd say it can be ignored.

Comment: Use XML or JSON instead, and serialize to objects!

Comment: I don't see the line you output that result

Comment: @Sakura I don't output it in that part. From here I take the `sError` variable and then set the text in a RichTextBox like this `errorBox.Text = sError;`

Comment: @Cistoran see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = @"#START#1 -- Contact#END#
#START#1 -- Error
2 -- Error
3 -- Error#END#
#START#1 -- Actions
2 -- Actions
3 -- Actions
4 -- Actions#END#
#START#1 -- Res
2 -- Res
3 -- Res#END#
#START#WorkedWith#END#
#START#3011#END#
#START#1 -- Details
2 -- Details
3 -- Details#END#";

        int k = -1;
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "#START#(.*?)#END#", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Variable " + ++k + " is:\n" + m.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

`"#START#(.*?)#END#"` will match anything between `#START#` and `#END#"` for you.

Result:

```
Variable 0 is:
1 -- Contact

Variable 1 is:
1 -- Error
2 -- Error
3 -- Error

Variable 2 is:
1 -- Actions
2 -- Actions
3 -- Actions
4 -- Actions

Variable 3 is:
1 -- Res
2 -- Res
3 -- Res

Variable 4 is:
WorkedWith

Variable 5 is:
3011

Variable 6 is:
1 -- Details
2 -- Details
3 -- Details
```

If you want to split result to lines you can use split to get desired variable.

```
int k = -1;
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "#START#(.*?)#END#", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled))
{
    k++;
    int k2 = -1;
    Console.WriteLine("Variable " + k + ":");
    foreach (var line in m.Groups[1].Value.Split('\n'))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Line " + ++k2 + ": " + line);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Result:

```
Variable 0:
Line 1: 1 -- Contact

Variable 1:
Line 1: 1 -- Error
Line 3: 2 -- Error
Line 5: 3 -- Error

Variable 2:
Line 1: 1 -- Actions
Line 3: 2 -- Actions
Line 5: 3 -- Actions
Line 7: 4 -- Actions

Variable 3:
Line 1: 1 -- Res
Line 3: 2 -- Res
Line 5: 3 -- Res

Variable 4:
Line 1: WorkedWith

Variable 5:
Line 1: 3011

Variable 6:
Line 1: 1 -- Details
Line 3: 2 -- Details
Line 5: 3 -- Details
```

Edit:

The whole below code is a waste, and wrong.

```
string sInput = "";
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sTemplateFilePath))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        sInput = sInput + line;

    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Change it to:

```
string sInput = File.ReadAllText(sTemplateFilePath);
```

**EDIT**

> @Sakura I need to assign each Regex match to a different variable. So
>   the first match goes into Variable1, the second match goes in
>   Variable2, the third match goes in Variable3. Does that make sense? –

Is this what you need?

```
int k = 0;
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(sInput, "#START#(.*?)#END#", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled))
{
    k++;
    switch (k)
    {
        case 1:
            var1 = m.Groups[1].Value;
            break;
        case 2:
            //var2...
            break;
    }
    foreach (var line in m.Groups[1].Value.Split('\n'))
    {
        switch (iLineCount)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to his specification each parsed variable could contain multi-line content, therefore I any further splitting out of lines is outside the scope of the question or answer.

Comment: @Sakura This is pretty much what I was looking for. [Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/zsikcg5W) I have to populate it into variables. The only issue is that it doesn't keep the line breaks as stored in the program. The output looks more [like this.](http://pastebin.com/BzSLpBtY)

Comment: @Sakura I added it for you.

Comment: @Sakura Now it breaks the lines up properly, but because I'm using `iLineCount` and incrementing it every time it goes through the foreach loop, my switch statement breaks it. How do I get the value of a specific match of the Regex? Ex. If I want to take the first match Regex finds and assign it to a specific variable?

Comment: @Sakura I need to assign each Regex match to a different variable. So the first match goes into Variable1, the second match goes in Variable2, the third match goes in Variable3. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Cistoran see my edit

Comment: @Sakura Yes that's exactly what I needed! So I was right in using a switch statement, I was just incrementing the variable in the wrong place. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the `Regex` class with a capture group to get the content between the `#BEGIN#` and `#END#` delimiters.  I'm guessing that you want to discard text otherwise.  The regular expression would look something like:

`#BEGIN#(.*?)#END#`

The capture group (#1) is indicated by the parenthesis and will contain the delimited text.  You can iterate through the content by loading it into a string buffer with this regex terminating when there are no remaining matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSV file. They are literally made for what you are trying to do. If you don't want to use commas you can always change the delimiter by specifying in the files additional properties.

You can use rows to separate multiples like you have in between the custom delimiters in your post. I apologize if I missed something.

Comment: A CSV file may or may not be an option.  Sometimes the format of a file that has to be processed is externally defined- by a client, a professor, an industry or government standard, etc.  The OP did not specify whether or not the he has the discretion to change the format described.  I think we should ask rather than assume.

Comment: Good point. I hope my answer was not misinterpreted as condescending.

Comment: No you did not come across that way.  (not to me anyway)  And I hope I did not come across reproachful as that was not my intention.  I agree with your main point that the file content should be kept simple (like a CSV file) if one has that option and no reason to believe that would otherwise cause difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own parser. It's really simple. Here I'm making an assumption that `#START#` and `#END#` are each on its own line (you can enforce it with search&replace or with C# code)

```
    private List<List<string>> parseData(string data)
    {
        List<List<string>> allValues = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> currentValues = null;

        // Assume that each line has only one entry
        foreach (var line in data.Split(new [] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            if (line == "#START#")
            {
                currentValues = new List<string>();
            }
            else if (line == "#END#")
            {
                allValues.Add(currentValues);
            }
            else
            {
                currentValues.Add(line);
            }
        }
        return allValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answers pointing towards regex or writing your own parser, I'd like to suggest using [FileHelpers library](http://www.filehelpers.net/).

Reading a delimited file would sort of look like this; first define a class matching a single file record:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderID;

    public string CustomerID;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
    public DateTime OrderDate;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")] // The decimal separator is .
    public decimal Freight;
}
```

Reading the file:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();
var records = engine.ReadFile("Input.txt");

foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record.CustomerID);
    Console.WriteLine(record.OrderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    Console.WriteLine(record.Freight);
}
```